# Setup SMTP setting in wordpress

Tags: plugins, email

My contact form in wordpress is not working. When the contact form is submitting, I get the following message

> Message sending failed " ... the SMTP setting is not configured..

How can I make the Mail to send. I'm using the plugin Contact Form7. How can I set up the email so that it will send to the user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress uses PHPMailer class and has an action hook that you can use to configure it. For example:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'cyb_smtp_config' );
function cyb_smtp_config( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.mailer.com';
    $phpmailer->Port = 25;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'username';
    $phpmailer->Password = 'password';
}
```

Be sure that you need a custom SMTP connection instead of configuring the SMTP service in your hosting. If you are not sure, contact with your hosting provider.

Comment: where i have to put this function .... ??   i have to write it in the function.php ??? or any where else ...

Comment: In functions.php or in a plugin file